# Using transactions in Azure mobile service custom API

Tags: javascript, azure, transactions, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I'm using a azure mobile service with a javascript backend to execute a custom API.

I need to execute several independent sql statements (delete, update). I need to have a transaction to insure that I only commit if all the sql statements have succeeded.

I am finding it difficult to find much documentation regarding this.

I started here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554212.aspx, and as instructed called connection.beginTransaction()

```
mssql.open({
            success: function(connection) {

                connection.beginTransaction();
                ...
```

I don't know how I should proceed from there. If I then try to execute a normal delete sql statement using the connection object I get the following error:

```
connection.query(deleteStatement, [parameter1, ], {
                                    success: function(results)
                                    {
                                        connection.commit();
                                        response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : '' });
                                    },
                                    error: function(err) {
                                       connection.rollback();
                                       console.log("error: " + err);
                                       response.send(statusCodes.Error, {message : err});
                                    }
                                });
```

> Error: [msnodesql] Invalid parameter(s) passed to function query or
>   queryRaw.

On the other hand if I execute the same query (with the same syntax) on the original mssql object it would appear that the connection.commit() and connection.rollback() statements do nothing. The query works, items do get deleted... But they get deleted even if I call connection.rollback() as the last step.

I expect I should be calling connection.query and passing in the transaction... somehow. I can not find any documentation regarding this.

How does one properly implement transactions in Azure Mobile Service - Custom API (javascript backend)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work. It turns out the syntax for this is quite a bit different than expected. I couldn't find any documentation regarding this, it looks like we are pretty much on our own when it comes to transactions.

This is what I ended up using:

```
var mssql = request.service.mssql;

mssql.open({
    success: function(connection) {
        connection.beginTransaction( function (error)
            {
                var statement1 = 'delete ... where X = ?'

                connection.query(statement1, [parameter1, ], function(err, results)
                    {
                        if (!isBlank(err))
                        {
                            console.log("Error:" + err);
                            connection.rollback();
                            response.send(statusCodes.Error, {message : ''});
                            connection.close();
                            return;
                        }

                        var statement2 = 'delete ... where X = ?'

                        connection.query(statement2, [parameter2, ], function(err, results)
                            {
                                if (!isBlank(err))
                                {
                                    console.log("Error:" + err);
                                    connection.rollback();
                                    response.send(statusCodes.Error, {message : ''});
                                    connection.close();
                                    return;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //daisy chain more statements if necessary. When the last one succeeds:
                                    connection.commit();
                                    response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : '' });
                                    connection.close();
                                }
                            }
                    });
                }
            },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log("Error : " + err);
        response.send(statusCodes.Error, {message : err});
    }
});
```

I find this syntax troublesome, but it works. Any improvements or suggestiosn on this pattern are more than welcome!

Comment: Your connection.query function calls seem to be missing a closing );

Comment: Thanks @Joel. I think of this more as a pseudocode, but I have added it, hopefully someone finds it useful.

Comment: I found it very useful. The lack of documentation on the connection methods is frustrating.

Comment: @DavidBožjak what is isBlank referring to?

Answer (score 1):

The mssql.open function returns an object of node-sqlserver.open; it's just been piped with your connection string. We're working on updating this documentation. You can look at the github project for node-sqlserver and look at the unit tests: https://github.com/Azure/node-sqlserver

Working on actively getting the documentation fixed up for this - sorry for the trouble.